# Is the liquid that gives Black Panther his powers the same which strips out his powers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

In *Black Panther* we have seen T'Challa's power being stripped away during ritual combat. So is that the same liquid which gives him power in the first place or is it a different herb? Could it nullify the powers of any other superhuman being, too?

Comment: first part of your question is ok. The second part is speculation.

Answer (score 9):

We don't have any information (that I can find) on what the "power-removing" liquid is made from or its effectiveness on powers in general.

I do NOT believe it is the same liquid as *gives* the powers, that's just not really logical.

It seems *likely* however, that it merely neutralizes the effects (quite rapidly) of the Heart-Shaped Herb on the human body thus removing the Black Panther powers.

If that *is* its only property then it would have no effect on other superheroes who get their abilities from myriad other sources.